# 5 centered arch construction with a known Height & Width

Tags: geometry

I am trying to construct a precise *5 centered arch* with a known Height & Width using a Pixel Processor contained in the software Substance Designer.

I found out this construction method from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tag4.jpg) image in the book “Practical Geometry for Builders and Architects” from 1921.

[image]

> Set out the Span (**JK**= ½  span) and the rise **KO**.
>
> With **K** as the center and radius **KO** describe the Arch **Oa**.
>
> Then **Ka** = **OK** + the rise.
>
> Describe a semicircle **Ja**.   At **K**, the junction of the longer
>   line **JK** with the shorter line **Ka**, produce **KO** to meet the
>   semicircle at **b**.
>
> **Kb** is the geometric mean or mean proportional between **JK** and
>   **KO**.
>
> From **O** set out **Oe** = **Kb**.
>
> From **O** set out **OV** = span = 2**JK**. With **J** as center and
>   radius **Kb** describe an arc **bd**
>
> With **V** as center and radius **Ve** describe an arc **ed** cutting
>   the arc **bd** at d**.**
>
> From **J** set out **Jr** = ½ rise = **OK**/2.
>
> Join **Vd** and produce to **3**.
>
> Join **Vr**. Join **dr** and produce to **1**.
>
> Then **V**, **d**, and **r** are the 3 centers for describing the 3
>   arches **O_3**; **3_1**; and **1_J** respectively with radii **VO**,
>   **d3** and **r1**.
>
> The 2 other centers corresponding with **r** and **d** may be
>   determined in a similar manner for describing the arcs which make up
>   the remainder of the outline of the arch to the right of OK.

I followed all the instructions but I can not seem to obtain a perfect junction between the main arc **O_3** and the other 2 on the right and 2 on the left (which instead are correctly merging). Here I link a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tjSu.jpg)  with 3 cases showing the problem.

The arcs should connect perfectly. Can anyone please help me spot my mistake? Is it possible that this construction method is flawed? 
I am trying to find a 5 centered arch construction method that works. 
Many thanks

Comment: Wow, that author's directions are hard to follow, what with the upper- and lower-case point names. The fuzzy screenshot made me see "$\delta$" instead of "$b$"! :) And then the points named with *numbers* had me confused at the end there. ... whew ... In any case, I *think* I followed the directions properly, and I agree with you: things don't match. It's certainly possible that the construction is wrong; mistakes happen. It's not clear to me (yet) where the error might be, either in the directions or the implementation. I need some time to wrap my brain around that construction.

Comment: Hi Blue. First of all thanks for helping.

Comment: I agree the instructionscould be clearer. It is the best resolution I could find sadly. But I just found another construction method. Similar BUT not identical. And surprisingy enough, it also produces the same identical problem. It is in the mid section of this article. https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/math/ellipse.htm (it is also easier to read). Something must be wrong, because I can't imagine these methods be so flawed.

Comment: You should have a look at [this document](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/148a/d9806fee3d1009cc72e4807c9d7aa01fac4b.pdf). Besides, the criterion for having a perfect (=smooth) junction at a certain point $P$ is that, if we denote the centers $C_1$ and $C_2$ of arcs connecting at point $P$ are such that $P,C_1,C_2$ are aligned.

Comment: Hi Jean Marie, thanks! I'll check it out in the next hours :)

Comment: I do think that in my constructions all the relevant arc centers are aligned though.

Comment: If we say that the ellipse has major and minor radii $p$ and $q$, the radius of curvature at the ends of the major and minor axes *should be* ([via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature#Ellipses)) $q^2/p$ and $p^2/q$, respectively. Yet, the construction (without even having to deal with any of the complicated stuff) approximates the ellipse at those ends by circular arcs of radius $q/2$ and $2p$. That's great if $p=2q$, but *generally*? Hmmm ...

Comment: I am surprised that the method is so flawed. I managed to construct a 3 point arch without troubles and the 3 arcs merge perfectly in that case.